# Show that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent $N(0, 1)$-distributed random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

> > The random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and $\mathcal N(0, 1)$-distributed.
> >     Set
> >     $$Y_1=\frac{X_1^2-X_2^2}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}} $$ and 
> >     $$Y_2=\frac{2X_1\cdot X_2}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}} $$
>
> I want to show that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent $\mathcal N(0, 1)$-distributed random variables.

My idea was to define $X_1$ and $X_2$ as functions of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, find the Jacobian and use the fact that we know the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ to find $f_{Y_1,Y_2}$. If the density $f_{Y_1,Y_2}$ turns out to be multivariate normal with a covariance matrix being diagonal (uncorrelated), then we know that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent and normally distributed. Am I correct?

If yes, then I need help finding the Jacobian. I have a hard time defining $X_1$ and $X_2$ as functions of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and dealing with the fact that the transformation has to be bijective.

And of course, any other approach would be appreciated as well. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a polar transformation, $X_1 = r\cos(\theta), X_2 = r\sin(\theta)$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2647442/321264.

Comment: This seems like a nice illustrative example of a question that it is reasonable to up-vote while also voting to close it (because it's a duplicate).

Comment: These definitions of $Y_1,Y_2$ are written in a way that is suggestive of trigonometric identities: $$ \begin{align} \cos(2a) & = \cos^2 a - \sin^2 a \\ \sin(2a) & = 2\sin a\cos a \\ 1 & = \cos^2 a + \sin^2 a \end{align} $$