# Find the PDF of $U = {XY \over \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ where $X, Y \sim N(0, 1)$ where X,Y are iid RV. Hence find the mean and variance of $U$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The task is to find the PDF of $U = {XY \over \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ where $X, Y \sim N(0, 1)$ where $X,Y$ are iid RV.

I approached this question as first finding the joint distribution of $g_{UV}(u, v)$ where $V = Y$ and then calculate the marginal distribution of $g_U(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_{UV}(u, v) dv$. But the final step becomes so messy as follow
$$
g_U(u)
 = {1 \over 2\pi}
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
        \exp\bigg(-\frac{v^3 + u^2v^2-u^2v+v}{2(v^2 - u^2)}\bigg)
            \bigg(\frac{v}{\sqrt{v^2 - u^2}}
                - \frac{uv^2}{(v^2 - u^2)^{3/2}}\bigg) dv.
$$

How can I proceed from here? Or is there a better or more efficient method to approach this question.

Comment: I have found similar problems as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647442/given-that-x-y-are-independent-n0-1-show-that-fracxy-sqrtx2y2  and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333295/if-x-and-y-are-independent-normal-variables-each-with-mean-zero-then-frac/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $X,\,Y$ are independent, the joint infinitesimal probability of $X,\,Y$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\frac{-x^2-y^2}{2}dxdy=\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}r\exp\frac{-r^2}{2}dr$. Since $U=\tfrac12R\sin2\Theta$, define $V:=\tfrac12R\cos2\Theta$ so$$\frac{dudv}{drd\theta}=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
u_{r} & v_{r}\\
u_{\theta} & v_{\theta}
\end{array}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
u/r & v/r\\
2v & -2u
\end{array}\right|=-2\frac{u^{2}+v^{2}}{r}=-\frac{r}{2}.$$So the joint PDF of $U,\,V$ is$$\frac{1}{2\pi}re^{-r^{2}/2}\frac{2}{r}dudv=\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-2\left(u^{2}+v^{2}\right)}dudv.$$Hence $U,\,V$ are $N\left(0,\,\tfrac{1}{4}\right)$ IIDs.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Two-time transformation is the trick here.